# How to pass different values to angular material mat-select?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have three selects controls inside `FormGroup`. Now I want to implement that after user selected province then fetching city data and selecting county data by passing `provinceCode` and `cityCode` as parameters respectively.
**City/Province/County** is a object like `{cityCode:'xxx',name:'xxx'}`. The `mat-select`'s `selectionChange` event pass the `mat-option`'s value. If I change the `mat-option`'s value to `city.name`, it's satisfied backend api's requirement, but I can't get counties data. Is there a solution to this situation? Angular version and Angular-Material version are both 12.

```html
<h2 mat-dialog-title>{{ ("::New" | abpLocalization) + ("::Company" | abpLocalization) }}</h2>
<mat-dialog-content>
  <form [formGroup]="form" class="form-container">
    <mat-form-field class="w-100">
      <mat-label
        >{{ ("::Company" | abpLocalization) + ("::Name" | abpLocalization) }}
        <span> * </span></mat-label
      >
      <input type="text" id="name" matInput formControlName="name" />
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field class="w-100">
      <mat-label>{{ "::UniformSocialCreditCode" | abpLocalization }} <span> * </span></mat-label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="uniform-social-credit-code"
        matInput
        formControlName="uniformSocialCreditCode"
      />
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field class="w-100">
      <mat-label>{{ "::Province" | abpLocalization }}<span> * </span></mat-label>
      <mat-select id="province" formControlName="province" (selectionChange)="getCities($event)">
        <mat-option [value]="province" *ngFor="let province of provinces">
          {{ province.name }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="w-100">
      <mat-label>{{ "::City" | abpLocalization }}<span> * </span></mat-label>
      <mat-select id="city" formControlName="city" (selectionChange)="getCounties($event)">
        <mat-option [value]="city" *ngFor="let city of cities">{{ city.name }}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="w-100">
      <mat-label>{{ "::County" | abpLocalization }}<span> * </span></mat-label>
      <mat-select id="county" formControlName="county">
        <mat-option [value]="county.name" *ngFor="let county of counties">
          {{ county.name }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field class="w-100">
      <mat-label>{{ "::Street" | abpLocalization }} <span> * </span></mat-label>
      <input type="text" id="street" matInput formControlName="street" />
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field class="w-100">
      <mat-label>{{ "::ZipCode" | abpLocalization }} <span> * </span></mat-label>
      <input type="text" id="zip-code" matInput formControlName="zipCode" />
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>{{ "::Close" | abpLocalization }}</button>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [mat-dialog-close]="getFormValue()">
    {{ "::Save" | abpLocalization }}
  </button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

And typescript is shown below

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS } from "@angular/material/dialog";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { AddressService } from 'src/app/address.service';
import { CityOptionDto, CountyOptionDto, ProvinceOptionDto } from 'src/app/provinceOptionDto';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-company-dialog',
  templateUrl: './company-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./company-dialog.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
      useValue: { hasBackdrop: true, width: "50vw" },
    }
  ]
})
export class CompanyDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  provinces: ProvinceOptionDto[];
  cities: CityOptionDto[];
  counties: CountyOptionDto[]
  selectedProvince: string;
  selectedCity: string;
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private addressService: AddressService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.buildForm();
    this.addressService.getProvinces().subscribe(x => this.provinces = x);
  }

  buildForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      uniformSocialCreditCode: ['', Validators.required],
      province: ['', Validators.required],
      city: ['', Validators.required],
      county: ['', Validators.required],
      street: ['', Validators.required],
      zipCode: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  getCities(province) {
    this.selectedProvince = province.value.name
    this.addressService.getCitiesByProvinceCode(province.value.provinceCode).subscribe(res => {
      this.cities = res;
    });
  }

  getCounties(city) {
    this.selectedCity = city.value.name
    this.addressService.getCountiesByProvinceCode(city.value.cityCode).subscribe(res => {
      this.counties = res;
    });
  }

  getFormValue() {
    this.form.patchValue({
      province: this.selectedProvince,
      city: this.selectedCity
    });
    return this.form.value;
  }

}
```

I tried add two properties to store the selected value and use `FormGroup.patchValue` method to modify the form value. It works for backend's api, but the `mat-select` element doesn't show the selected option.

### Update 2022/1/9 Add API description

```
createCompany(name:string, uniformSocialCreditCode:string, province:string, city:string, county:string, zipCode:string)


getProvinces() ----> response structure [{name:'xxx',provinceCode:'xxx'},{name:'xxx',provinceCode:'xxx'}]


getCities(provinceCode:string) ----> response structure [{name:'xxx',cityCode:'xxx'},{name:'xxx',cityCode:'xxx'}]

getCounties(cityCode:string) ----> response structure [{name:'xxx',countyCode:'xxx'},{name:'xxx',countyCode:'xxx'}]
```

I need `provinceCode` to fill city selection element and `cityCode` to fill county selection element. If I don't set `province` object as mat-option's value, I can't get province code from the value.  When I submit the form, the createCompany'a parameters(province:string --> object, city:string---> object) changes.

Comment: Can you provide sample of api's response you're working with and getting city/province/county from?

Comment: @MishaMashina getProvince()  returns array of province, getCities(provinceCode) returns array of city and getCounties(cityCode) returns array of county. Province, city and county all like {xxxCode: '10001', name: 'xxx'}. Actually I want to pass provinceCode to api and only submit province's name not all province object. So what I should do?

Comment: from your question it's not clear if your issue is with your API or in UI. Does your API return the response as expected? Kindly share the response.

Comment: @VimalPatel the API need code(province or city) to get next level data, and create 
 company api just need names of province and city. If I pass province to mat-option's value this wil throw exception. So I need pass code to call API and pass name to call create api. What I should do?

Comment: Kindly share your API schema and response structure.